# Using AsyncTask to start activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using asyncTask to show Dialog and then after few minutes then launch a new activity.

unfortunately that activity start before task finished ???

```
package com.android.grad;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public LoginTask(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Signing in",
            "Please wait while we are signing you in..");
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    pd.dismiss();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, Boolean.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

and i execute the task from button click listener :S

```
private OnClickListener loginOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new LoginTask(LoginActivity.this).execute();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BuiltInCamera.class));
        }
    };
```

Is there way to startActivity from my subClass ofAsyncTask .

Comment: yes, you should start it in your onPostExecute method, right after you show your Toast

Comment: the method cannot call inside onPostExecute

Comment: improve your acceptancy rate..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you can start activity from AsyncTask's sub class. See below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, Boolean.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, BuiltInCamera.class));
}
```

After making this change, make sure you do remove **startActivity** from `OnClickListener`

Comment: What does the activity come? (new Intent(activity, ...)

Comment: `activity` is the reference to your Activity i.e. received through the AsyncTask's constructor.

Comment: And if the activity is destroyed?

Comment: then it will crash. for safe side make a check if `activity != null` before using its reference

Answer (score 5):

Call `startActivity` inside `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`

Comment: the method is not found :S
i try it more and more

Comment: u should use YourClassActivityName.this.startActivity. Then it will work

Answer (score 5):

Call this `startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BuiltInCamera.class));` from `onPostExecute()` after Displaying toast message.

In this way, new activity will be called after your `AsyncTask` is over.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PageViewActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    activity.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it works fine but in my try the activity run for tow time - one in new activity ( first line - and second in third line