# Why Custom progress bar is not animating in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

Here in may application i have implement custom Progress bar but custom progress bar

**1st Issue:** 
1st issue is that Progress Bar just showing and not animating, i have use asynctask for loading heavy data  from external database in Background.

**2nd Issue:** The 2nd one problem is that when i click on link to load heavy data then it switch on another activity that show the loaded result.The problem is that when i press a link for load data it take 7-8 sec, and showing a black screen for  3-4 sec when switching another screen how can i avoid to showing black screen?

Mean when i press link for load data it take 3-4 SEC, on(1st screen) current screen, then appear black screen for 3-4 sec then show (2nd screen) for result, i don't know why it is happening, and how i can avoid it.
I want when i click on link then one progress bar should be execute and goes secondActivity,without showing black screen.
please where i should use progress dialog on 1st screen(current screen) or second screen? or on both screen? please any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Custom adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_navitem,null);
    holder.tv=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvlstName);

    holder.tv.setTypeface(face);
    holder.img=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);

    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
   rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       //Toast.makeText(context,"you Clicked "+result[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       if(result[position]=="کھانوں کی فہرست".trim().toString())
                                       {

                                           new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                                               @ Override
                                               protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
                                                   //for progress bar
                                                   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                                                   progressDialog.show ( ) ;
                                                   progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
                                                   progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

                                               }
                                               @Override
                                               protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                                           //stuff that updates ui
                                                           context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class));



                                                   return null ;
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                                                   if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                   }
                                               }


                                           }.execute(null, null, null);

                                       }
```

When screen switch SecondActivity.class then show black screen.

Here is the SecondActivity  class some relevant code.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
public static Typeface face;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/asunaskh.ttf");



    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.sectoolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout=(CollapsingToolbarLayout)
         findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
   collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("کھانے کی فہرست");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(face);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTypeface(face);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @ Override
        protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
            progressDialog.show ( ) ;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //stuff that updates ui
                    show_card();
                                        }
            });

            return null ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
//show_card() method goes here
public void show_card(){....}
```

This is a custom progress bar that show before switch SecondActivity when i click to a link
[Custom Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUmKp.png)

Here is 2nd screen shot(black screen) of Progress BAr when activity switch form current to another activity.
[Progress Bar Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mkTN.png)

Answer (score 0):

**1st Issue:** You will need to implement `onProgressUpdate()` in your `AsyncTask` to animate your progress bar. See [documentation for AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

**2nd Issue:** I think the issue here is that you are starting the second activity from the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` which does not run on the UI thread. (Activities should run on the UI thread.) `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` both run on the UI thread, so you might move the start of the second activity there. If the only thing the `AsyncTask` is doing is to start the `Activity` then you don't need the `AsyncTask` at all - just start the `Activity`.

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737016/using-asynctask-to-start-activity) and the accepted answer for some guidance.